# changing slide direction and position of slide menu

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change slide direction and position of slide menu when I click on hanburger button.

http://www.dickiesmedical.kr/

At this site, slide menu moves(shows) from left to right when hamburger button is pressed.

But, I want the slide menu to move from right to left (it must starts from right end of brower)

help~

Comment: show us some code for review that you have used so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace left:0; to right:0; in #sidemenu.is_show .core class and replace #sidemenu .core
left:-300px; to right:-300px;